# su command in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I have a script which copies a file, then untar and install it (agent-service) on multiple systems (IPs are read from systems.txt file). In the script, I wanted to start the agent-service as user "test". However after the script execution, when I check the target system, the agent-service is shown as running as "root" user. What could be wrong here? Am I not using su command correct within the script?

```
~]# ps -ef | grep agent-service

    root     23511 15196  0 02:12 pts/3    00:00:00 agent-service
```

Script>

```
#!/bin/bash
export AGENT=linux-5.8.1.tar.gz

while read host; do

scp $AGENT root@$host:/opt


ssh -n root@$host 'cd /opt/linux;
tar zxvf linux-5.8.1.tar.gz;
mkdir /opt/hyperic;
useradd -m test;
chown -R test:test /opt/linux;
su - test;
/opt/linux/agent-service start'

done < systems.txt
```

Comment: That reads as: switch to user test, which has nothing to do, finishes, and then run that start as the original user. If you keep it in one line it might work (`su -c the-command`). BTW: there are things like `start-stop-daemon` which take care of a lot of things you might find useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `su` as you do here spawns a new shell that has nothing to do thus exits immediately.

Either pass the command to `su`:

```
su - test -c /opt/linux/agent-service start
```

Or use `sudo` in a similar manner:

```
sudo -u test /opt/linux/agent-service start
```

Comment: thanks much, that helped. updated the script as below and it worked. su -c "/opt/linux/agent-service start" test